# Clarification in sentence usage

Tags: sentence

I want to rephrase this:

> "No member in my group is pending to clear the certification".

May I say "No one is yet to be certified"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be clearer if you said

> *no-one's certification is pending*

or (better)

> *no certifications are pending*

It's not clear, but I doubt we can say

> *everyone is certified*

Comment: Do you mean to say "No-one is pending for certification"?

Comment: No -- what's pending is *certification* not the people who want to be certified.